# Endpoint to get the evaluation of the overall application from Google Play

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, review, publisher

I want to get the evaluation of the overall application. I have access to scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher but reviews list does not return the overall evaluation for application (only evaluation of the application according to the person, review). It is possible to get this evaluation? Maybe I must have access to different scope?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The current average star rating of the application is not available by any API in Google Play. I assume this is what you are asking for.